# hast du schon gerich/krikk/krieg ...?

Tags: verb, austrian

I hear a word very often that sounds like "krig" or "krieg" or "gerich". Seems to be a fairly local or shortened version of something else. From the content I think it means something along the lines of "doing it" or "actioning something". I know that there is historical use of the word "krieg" (war) which, overtime became an action word similar to "get" -> kriegen. So perhaps this is just the locals way of saying it, but when said so fast it just sounds like "krik".

For example:
"Hast du schon *"krik"*? - I guess means "have you done it already" or maybe "are you getting it" or "are you actioning it".

Can anyone give me further info on the Hochdeutsch version and the "dirty Tyrolean" version they seem to be using :D. Difficult to pin down because I don't know if they are saying it in the past or present tense. (Are you doing it, have you done it, will you do it...maybe?).

Comment: I like these kind of questions! Keep 'em coming! :)

Comment: No, please ask the people you are talking to, what they mean. We have no way to veriify, what they meant; it is just speculation and guess work.

Comment: @userunknown No, this is not guesswork. The Tyrolese dialect is not some kind of secret language. There are 100,000's of speakers and also people from other parts of Austria will know what OP is referring to.

Comment: @idmean: If the  Tyrolese dialect was written, not spoken, then you would be right. Der User hat ja selbst die Verbindung "kriegen" als "to get" benannt - dennoch scheint er vom Kontext her auf "done it" zu tippen. Wieso fragt er nicht die Sprecher, sondern uns?

Comment: @idmean es war keine Frage an mich, ich habe sie nur mitgehört, also wäre es seltsam  sie zu fragen. Und die Leute auf stackoverflow können mir eine größere Erklärung geben, die ich lernen kann

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the main point of confusion here is that Bavarian dialects, to which Tyrolian belongs, tend to leave out the `ge-` prefex from the past participle in many instances*.  The verb you looking for is *kriegen*, a colloquial equivalent to *bekommen*.

> Er hat es gekriegt.
>
> Hast du es gekriegt?

or, in "dirty Tyrolian" (with dialect pseudo spelling):

> Ea hots kchriag(t).
>
> Hoscht es kchriag(t)?

where *ch* is the typical [χ] fricative of South Bavarian, and the *t* at the end will often be inaudible.  The long [i] becomes an opening diphthong [ia].  So your "gerich" is most likely *kchriach* (the final *g* becoming a fricative, too).

A Tyrolian speaker trying to stick a bit more closely to (Austrian) standard might also say something like

> Er hots gekchriagt.
>
> Hos(ch)t es gekchriagt?

---

*There is some regularity to when this happens: historically, the prefix had been used to "perfectivize" otherwise imperfective verbs (or maybe "telitize" atelic verbs); from that, the past participle developed.  Verbs that already have a perfective meaning (e.g., *finden*, *treffen*, *bringen*, *pflücken*) don't need that, and thus got not *ge* until Early New High German.  This is preserved in Bavarian dialects.  (There is some leeway in the semantic interpretation, though: *finden* **does** have *ge* in the dialects I know.)

Comment: Thanks. I think this is more likely the answer - that they are swallowing the "ge" part. However this time around there was a very definitive "K" in the tone at the start of the word, which I would assume had some significance, almost as if they are pushing the fact that they are not simply swallowing the "ge", but stating definitively that they mean "Kriegt". But then again, maybe that's just how they say it here.

Comment: What you perceive might be the result of two things: (1) the fact that these consonants are very "hard" -- /g/ is realized usually unvoiced as almost [k], and /k/ strongly aspirated or turned into the affricate [kχ]. And (2), the intonation of questions in Tyrolian tends to use a rising or rising-falling contour, similar to an exclamation, instead of the more usual falling with a dip at the end.

Comment: ...which makes it easy to parodize: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sHBovz2jUdA.

Answer (score 4):

> Hast du's schon hingekriegt?

> Have you worked it out yet?
> Did you get it right yet?

That would be my first association. I was born and live in Berlin, so it's not an expert answer, but it would fit the context described.

See more at [wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/hinkriegen); there is an example:

> [1](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/hinkriegen) [Kollege:] „Können Sie mir helfen, ich **kriege** das nicht **hin**.“

Answer (score 4):

My best guess is, that you heard

> Hast du's schon gekriegt?" (colloquial)

meaning: did you already receive it? In written German one would replace the verb by *bekommen*. Depending on local dialect it may sound more like *gekricht*.

*Kriegen* can be combined with many prefixes, and *hinkriegen*, *reinkriegen* (get something delivered, as a shop person woould tell the customer) come to mind first.

Comment: I wondered what bothers me about my answer. nice (addition)!

Comment: Thanks. I definitely didn't hear the "ge" part. Because my previous research came to the same conclusion. This is what confused me the most. Because it's too open to suggestion, particularly when gekriegt can be prefixed by other parts like "hin". If they are swallowing the "ge" part, would they do the same with hingekriegt? hinkriegt? It  sounds so messy

Comment: The Bavarian _ge_-"dropping" is also applied when prefixes are involved, yes. You mustn't think of it so much as a "dropping", though, but as an alternative form where the participle just has no _ge_ at all; like the verbs on _ieren_: _servieren_ - _serviert_ - _abserviert_.